# Select Identity without 'into"

Tags: sql, select, identity, sql-server-2008

Alright, I'm 99% sure it's possible... How do I select an identity column without using 'into' in SSMS 2008?

For example,

I know this doesn't work, but it's what I'm looking for...

```
Select  PK as Identity (int,1,1), A.*
From    Table_1 A
```

Comment: What do you mean by Identity column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a random unique number, try:

```
Select  row_number() over (order by newid())
,       A.*
From    Table_1 A
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  It gave me a syntax error at first, needed to add () after the row_number.

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by newid()) AS ID, A.*
FROM Table_1 A

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create ID to data after getting whatever data using the SELECT. Where you may use within a UPDATE or a MERGE or some sort of DML.

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by newid()) AS ID, A.ColumnName
FROM (Select DISTINCT ColumnName From  Table_1)  A
```